# Bad search results due to sharding?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, tf-idf

I have the default configuration of the elastic search node: 5 shards and 1 replica. I query the node which matches on particular field which is the same for many documents in these 5 shards. However the search results have different scores due to the tf-idf for that query for that document in that particular shard. Ideal scenario for me would be to have the same score for the document for the same fields across different shards and I could break ties by ordering on a second criteria which is important to me. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that normal queries on Elasticsearch that span multiple shards use what's known as Query then Fetch:

> **Default search type: Query Then Fetch**
>
> By default, Elasticsearch will use a search type called “Query Then
>   Fetch“. The way it works is as follows:
>
> - Send the query to each shard
> - Find all matching documents and calculate scores using local    Term/Document Frequencies
> - Build a priority queue of results (sort, pagination with from/to,    etc)
> - Return metadata about the results to requesting node. Note, the    actual document is not sent yet, just the scores
> - Scores from all the shards are merged and sorted on the requesting    node, docs are selected according to query criteria
> - Finally, the actual docs are retrieved from individual shards where    they reside.
> - Results are returned to the client
>
> This system usually works fine. In most cases, your index has “enough”
>   documents to smooth out the Term/Document frequency statistics. So
>   while each shard may not have complete knowledge of frequencies across
>   the cluster, results are “good enough” because the frequencies are
>   fairly similar everywhere.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch/

The problem for you is that it calculates the TF-IDF score locally -

What you will want to try is using DFS Query then Fetch, which will pre-query all the shards and calculate the scores using a global, not local, term document/frequency:

> - Prequery each shard asking about Term and Document frequencies
> - Send the query to each shard
> - Find all matching documents and calculate scores using global    Term/Document Frequencies calculated from the prequery.
> - Build a priority queue of results (sort, pagination with from/to,    etc)
> - Return metadata about the results to requesting node. Note, the    actual document is not sent yet, just the scores
> - Scores from all the shards are merged and sorted on the requesting    node, docs are selected according to query criteria
> - Finally, the actual docs are retrieved from individual shards where    they reside.
> - Results are returned to the client

In your case I would use DFS Query then Fetch, but I'd also check out the various alternatives - Elasticsearch has a lot of flexibility in modifying the search request type:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html

Comment: is there a significant performance difference between dfs_query_then_fetch and query_then_fetch?

Comment: I'd say it's non-trivial, which is why the default is Query then Fetch. It's a classic trade-off of accuracy vs. performance, but the specific impact is a function of index sizes, number of docs and terms, hardware, etc.